# spark-submit gets idle in local mode

Tags: kerberos, cloudera, spark-submit

I am trying to test a jar using spark-submit (Spark 1.6.0) into a Cloudera cluster, which has Kerberos enabled.
The fact is that if I launch this command:

```
spark-submit --master local --class myDriver myApp.jar -c myConfig.conf
```

In local or local[*], the process stops after a couple of stages. However, if I use yarn-client or yarn-cluster master modes the process ends correctly. The process reads and writes some files into HDFS.

Furthermore, these traces appear:

```
17/07/05 16:12:51 WARN spark.SparkContext: Requesting executors is only supported in coarse-grained mode
17/07/05 16:12:51 WARN spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Unable to reach the cluster manager to request 1 total executors!
```

It is surely a matter of configuration, but the fact is that I don't know what is happenning. Any ideas? What configuration options should I change?